# Is there a better way to emulate an ENUM with typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am creating something similar to an ENUM in a base class / different file:

```
ExamStatusId = {
    All: {
        elem: this.examStatusSelectId, // << refers to a string
        text: 'Exam Status: All',
        val: 0
    },
    Current: {
        elem: this.examStatusSelectId, // << refers to a string
        text: 'Exam Status: Current',
        val: 1
    }
}
```

Once this is defined I call a function like this inside of another class / file:

```
page.isSelectedValue(page.ExamStatusId.All);
```

Here's the function that's in yet another class / file:

```
isSelectedValue (data) {
    var title = this.getTitle(data.id);
    var valueString = data.val.toString();
    it('Check for ' + data.text, function () {
        expect(data.elem.getAttribute("value")).toBe(valueString);
    });
}
```

This code works but can someone tell me if this is a better way for me to pass the data I need to the `isSelectedValue` function using Typescript? I already use Typescript for the code and would like to make the most of all the features it offers.

Also how can I ensure that what I pass to that function has all the parameters of elem, text and val ?

Comment: What's "ENUM" for you? Because if you'd like a proper ADT (which would be a "real" enumeration for me) then nope, Typescript's type system cannot really do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like the code below.
At least to me it looks like you are not using enums but more something like object constants?
This is something which can be done with a extra interface. The nice thing about this you still have typechecking in your isSelectedValue  function!

```
interface IElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
var ExamStatusId = {
    All: <IElement>{
        elem: this.examStatusSelectId, // << refers to a string
        text: 'Exam Status: All',
        val: 0
    },
    Current: <IElement>{
        elem: this.examStatusSelectId, // << refers to a string
        text: 'Exam Status: Current',
        val: 1
    }
}

function isSelectedValue (data: IElement) {
}

isSelectedValue(ExamStatusId.All);
```

Answer (score 5):

Typescript has built-in enum syntax:

```
enum EnumName {
    member1,
    member2,
    member3
}
```

EnumName then becomes a named type, so you could have a function:

```
((foo: EnumName) => { })(EnumName.member1);
```

In order to meet your specific request, perhaps you could do something like:

```
enum Status {
    All,
    Current
}
ExamStatusID = {
    elem: this.examStatusSelectId
    val: (status: Status) => {
        switch(status) {
            case Status.All: //etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a bit more of an example of how I could use this for my requirements. I am sorry but I don't understand much about Typescript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

enums are tedious sometimes when it comes to get the value of the same, here is what i user in that case

```
  export class urlMapper {
    //contains names of the api url's
    static homeUrl:string = '/home';
    static loginUrl:string ='/auth';
    static userUrl:string ='/user';
    static logoutUrl:string ='/logout';
    static storeUrl:string="/store";

}
```