# How can I access a property of a property declared with an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying this code:

```
export interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
export interface IIndexable<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}  
export class AdminBase {

    ExamStatusId: IIndexable<IEnumElement> = {
        All: {
            elem: "",
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: {
            elem: "asdf",
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
}

var x = new AdminBase();
var y = x.ExamStatusId.All;
```

It's giving me an error saying:

```
Error   1   The property 'All' does not exist on value of type 
'IIndexable<IEnumElement>'. C:\Protractor\TypeScript1.ts
```

Note that ExamStatusId has just two properties now but there could be any number of different properties later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out my answer to your previous question... you'll see that my solution does in fact allow access to the `All` property.

[Can I define an interface for every property of an object just the one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786918/can-i-define-an-interface-for-every-property-of-an-object-just-the-one-time)

Once again, I'll stress the beauty within TypeScript of leaning on *type inference*. You don't need to explicitly annotate everything in your program, you can let the compiler and language service do the hard work.

The "type inference version" of your code gives you:

- Type safety for IEnumElement at the point of consumption
- Type safety for `ExamStatusId` property *if you use it as an IEnumElement*
- Access to the `All` property
- Less hand-written annotations

Here is the full example:

```
interface IEnumElement {
    elem: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}

class Exam {
    private examStatusSelectId: number;

    ExamStatusId = {
        All: {
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            elem: '',
            text: 'Exam Status: All',
            val: 0
        },
        Current: {
            id: this.examStatusSelectId,
            elem: '',
            text: 'Exam Status: Current',
            val: 1
        }
    }
}

// This function must be passed an IEnumElement
function example(element: IEnumElement) {

}

var exam = new Exam();

// The compiler knows this is good
example(exam.ExamStatusId.All);
```

Comment: What we do see here, that you are working with a type `Exam`. This is a type defined *as is* ... But that's not the OP case - even if that could solve the issue ;). I am trying to explain how TypeScript dictionary does work - e.g. having type like  `IIndexable<IEnumElement>`. So while your example is working it is changing the implementation (which still could be correct) ;)

Comment: TypeScript allows us to bring a lot of existing class-based knowledge to JavaScript. We should, where possible, leave behind our knowledge of nominally typed systems and embrace the structural type system. If we are using TypeScript because it gives us static type checking, any solution that requires magic strings is inferior to a solution that is statically typed. Also, the implementation is not any different, it is just being expressed by the compiler, not the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

The point here, is that we declare the type of `ExamStatusId` to be implementing this interface `IIndexable<IEnumElement>`

```
ExamStatusId: IIndexable<IEnumElement>
```

And we also declared, that the `IIndexable<IEnumElement>` is having **`string`** key and element of type `T`:

```
export interface IIndexable<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}
```

So, the only way here how to acces that member is via string indexer:

```
var y = x.ExamStatusId["All"];
```

Comment: Would there be a way to change that if I was to change the [index: string]. Having to specify "All" in a string is a problem that I was trying to avoid as I can see problems if I enter "all" by mistake. do you think I should go back to this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781762/is-there-a-better-way-to-emulate-an-enum-with-typescript

Comment: I do understand! ;) 100%! I thought, when started to use this notation: "Hey, I am loosing type safety if I do type `ExamStatusId["All"]` instead of `ExamStatusId.All`..." But do you know what? that notation with pure JS `ExamStatusId.All` was also not save... and in the word of dictionaries in JAVA or C# ... dictionary is simply not type safe.. if you ask for a key... check it ex post.. and in Unit tests... Bad I know ;(... but ... *Final note: we can always do `(<any>ExamStatusId).all` ... but the small `a` instead of `All` will cause an error later...*

Comment: You can access it using `ExamStatusId.All` with full type safety. See my answer.